# Is there a default chess board editor/library that is used to display chess competitions on the web?

Tags: markdown, chess

I could not find enough credible information about this topic. I discover that a very good one is used to display chess competitions at https://chess.stackexchange.com/. Another one is used at http://www.chess.com

Requirements:

I want to use this with a markdown editor.

It is considered as default in the community.